# Split doesn't return empty string

Tags: ruby, split

Is there a way to obtain:

```
"[][][]".split('[]')
#=> ["", "", ""]
```

instead of

```
#=>[]
```

without having to write a function?

The behavior is surprising here because sometimes irb would respond as expected:

```
"[]a".split('[]')
#=>["", "a"]`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This really sounds like an XY Problem, where you're asking us how to do Y instead of X. Where does the data/string come from? Do you control its generation? It's very rare to see something like that in code. Please read "[ask]", including the links at the bottom of the page, and "[mcve]" along with http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153968

Comment: I disagree with the idea that this in unclear: the example is clear an minimal, and it makes sense that `String#split` would work in the way the OP expects. There's also a clear, specific answer (see Jordan's and my answers).

Comment: Thank you all for replying even if some of you don't think the question wasn't "correct".

Comment: This is a perfect question. I find it annoying that someone would actively discourage the exact type of question we want to see on SO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html):

> If the *limit* parameter is omitted, trailing null fields are suppressed. If *limit* is a positive number, at most that number of fields will be returned (if *limit* is `1`, the entire string is returned as the only entry in an array). If negative, there is no limit to the number of fields returned, and trailing null fields are not suppressed.

And so:

```
"[][][]".split("[]", -1)
# => ["", "", "", ""]
```

This yields four empty strings rather than your three, but if you think about it it's the only result that makes sense. If you split `,,,` on each comma you would expect to get four empty strings as well, since there's one empty item "before" the first comma and one "after" the last.

Comment: Seems we're looking at the same questions today! A+, would upvote again.

Comment: Thanks, It was exactly what I was looking for.  Don't know why i didn't look in the doc. and actually having ` ["","","",""] ` is what makes more sense.

Answer (score 3):

`String#split` takes two arguments: a `pattern` to split on, and a `limit` to the number of results returned. In this case, `limit` can help us.

The [documentation for `String#split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-split) says:

> If the *limit* parameter is omitted, trailing null fields are suppressed. If *limit* is a positive number, at most that number of fields will be returned (if *limit( is 1, the entire string is returned as the only entry in an array).

The key phrase here is *trailing null fields are suppressed*, in other words, if you have extra, empty matches at the end of the string, they'll be dropped from the result unless you have set a `limit`.

Here's an example:

```
"[]a[][]".split("[]")
#=> ["", "a"]
```

You might expect to get `["", "a", "", ""]`, but because *trailing null fields are suppressed*, everything after the last non-empty match (the `a`) is dropped.

We could set a limit, and only get that many results:

```
"[]a[][]".split("[]", 3)
#=> ["", "a", "[]"]
```

In this case, since we've asked for 3 results, the last `[]` is ignored and forms part of the last result. This is useful when we know how many results we expect, but not so useful in your specific case.

Fortunately, the docs continue:

> If negative, there is no *limit* to the number of fields returned, and trailing null fields are not suppressed.

In other words, we can pass a limit of `-1`, and get *all* the matches, even the trailing empty ones:

```
"[]a[][]".split('[]', -1)
#=> ["", "a", "", ""]
```

This even works when *all* the matches are empty:

```
"[][][]".split('[]', -1)
#=> ["", "", "", ""]
```